# Parsing an external JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse this external JSON file using JQuery:

```
var items={ "menu" : [ 
   {"id": "TN", "value": "ar"} ,
    {"id": "FR", "value": "fr"} ,
    {"id": "GB", "value": "en"} ,
    {"id": "US", "value": "en"} 
]
}
```

with this HTML file, I wander if there is a mistake with the syntax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your New Application</title>
<style type="text/css">
    /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
    *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
    input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
    body { background-color:white; color:black }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* This code is used to run as soon as Intel activates */
    var onDeviceReady=function(){
    //hide splash screen
    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
    };
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
</script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

    //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //after button is clicked we download the data
        $('.button').click(function(){

            //start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "pays.json",
                //force to handle it as text
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                    //and pass downloaded data
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //now json variable contains data in json format
                    //let's display a few items
                    $('#results').html('Country: ' + json.items.menu[0].id + '<br  />Language: ' + json.items.menu[0].value);
                }
            });
        });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="pays.json" target="_blank">Open JSON file</a><br />
<input type="button" value="Get and parse JSON" class="button" />
<br />
<span id="results"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I didn't get anything on the output. 
What is the mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no need to parse JSON. You can directly use data.menu[0].id

Answer (score 2):

If that first part is supposed to be the contents of the "external JSON" file, that's not JSON. That's just JavaScript to declare an object inside a file. Remove the `var items=` part so it's actually valid JSON, then you'd do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pays.json",
    //force to handle it as text
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#results').html('Country: ' + data.menu[0].id + '<br  />Language: ' + data.menu[0].value);
    }
});
```

I've taken out the call to `$.parseJSON()` because it's not needed. If you specify `dataType: 'json'` for the AJAX request the response is automatically parsed as JSON, and then the result (if parsing doesn't fail) is passed as the first argument to the `success` function. That means that inside of that function `data` is your object.

There's also no `items` property declared in your object, only `menu`, so I've changed it from `json.items.menu` to just `data.menu`.

Comment: I got this error:

**Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/myuser/Documents/pageweb/TestFailedPages/pays.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Comment: @user1444393 You'll need to run a server and deploy to that. Some (possibly all) browsers don't like AJAX requests from HTML pages loaded from your computer's file system.

Comment: By the way the Json file is under the same folder with the html file.

Comment: OK, based on this JSON file sample:
"licenses": [ { "type": "Apache", "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0" }, { "type": "GPL v2", "url": "http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html" } ], 



How can I extract informations on the HTML page? I mean I want to exctract the two type and the two url. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
   var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //now json variable contains data in json format
                    //let's display a few items
                    $('#results').html('Country: ' + json.items.menu[0].id + '<br  />Language: ' + json.items.menu[0].value);
                }
```

to

```
                //now json variable contains data in json format
                     var menu=data.items.menu;
                   for(var i in menu)
                      {
                         //let's display a few items
                       $('#results').html('Country: ' + menu[i].id + '<br     />Language: ' +menu[i].value);
```

}

```
            }
```

Comment: I got this error:

**Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/myuser/Documents/pageweb/TestFailedPages/pays.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Comment: By the way the Json file is under the same folder with the html file.

Comment: JSON load from your server or folder

Comment: it's loaded from my folder

Comment: Ajax not allow to load file from system,its possible from server

Comment: But when I execute this code:

http://runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery

it works perfectly with FireFox but not with Chrome. (and the json is under the same folder in the system)

Comment: see if you wand to display some data from json correct

Comment: By the way, is it data.item.menu OR data.items.menu?

Comment: see if you wand to display some data from json correct? HOW?

Comment: i get some JSON from server then i will display in html

Comment: see i wand user related information so ,i send a request to server then server response json format(using ajax)

Comment: example var user={name:'',id:'',mailid:''}

Comment: OK, based on this JSON file sample: "licenses": [ { "type": "Apache", "url": "apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"; }, { "type": "GPL v2", "url": "gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html"; } ], How can I extract informations on the HTML page? I mean I want to exctract the two type and the two url. Thanks!

Comment: can i know your server side language